# Align Instances to Curve with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, point-clouds

[image: Curve to mesh]
[image: Mesh zoom]

Using Blender 3.0.

Using the grease pencil, I've created a curve that I've then converted to a mesh (using *Object > Convert > Mesh*). I have a series of points that I can work with using geometry nodes. Those point instances are clearly laid out in the geometry node table:

[image: Geometry nodes table]

I want to instance a mesh for every single point in the curve, oriented along this curve. To do this, I could use the *Instance on Points* node:

[image: Cylinders on points]

However, I now need to reorient those meshes to follow the curve. I think I can access the XYZ coordinate of each point using *Input > Position* and splitting the result with a *Separate XYZ* node, however this gives me the position of each node, not the one of the node right before or right after, while I'd need those to determine the orientation and the scale of every mesh element.

How can I access the n+1 or n-1 point to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Align Instances to Curve**

If it's not too late, perhaps it's easier to defer the conversion of Curve to Mesh, and let Geometry Nodes do it for you, if you need to do it at all.

Then, when using the *Curve to Points* node, you have access to the curve's  `Tangent` and `Normal` attributes in the GN tree, and the `Rotation` convenience combination, which interprets the curve's tangential direction at the points as Z:

[image]

This also leaves you the option of resampling the curve, changing the curve's own profile if you want to display it as a mesh, and so on.