# Align object along curve (Geometry Node 3.0)

Tags: geometry-nodes

There is a sphere with a hole along Y axis to mark the rotation. This sphere is instanced along a curve with resampled points. Now I want to align the sphere along the curve so that the holes are on the curve. How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: No blame, (this answer wasn't easy to find, I've edited it to make it more searchable) but this question is a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/242623/35559 By default, it's easier to put the hole along the Z axis.

Comment: @Gorgious Yeap that is happen ... consider remove notification comment as well :)

Comment: @RobinBetts Yes, that's the solution :)